# Updated Ubuntu 11.04 from 10.x and vim's menu bar disappeared

Tags: vim, ubuntu-11.04

Since the update gvim no longer displays a menu.  The toolbar continues to work as expected.

I have tried 
:set guioptions-=m
:set guioptions+=m

From within vim, and on advice from a similar problem have first removed 
`~/.gnome2/Vim` (which did not help) then edited `~/.gnome2/Vim`, changed

```
[Placement]
Dock=Toolbar\\0,1,0,0\\Menubar\\0,0,0,0
```

to

```
[Placement]
Dock=Toolbar\\0,1,0,0\\Menubar\\0,0,0,1
```

But neither of these things helps.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: However - it turns out that if I run `gvim -f` from the command line rather than `gvim` then all works and I have the expected menu.

Comment: The -f option only asks gvim to stay in the foreground (rather than detach from the console as gvim does normally).  It should not make any difference but does fix the problem.

Comment: Same problem here .. I have the feeling that Unity is the culprit.

Comment: Something new on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in this order, it worked for me:

:set guioptions-=m

:set guioptions-=T

:set guioptions+=m

:set guioptions+=T